# Serialize object with field of type MkFieldLens

Tags: scala, serialization, typeclass, shapeless, lenses

**How can I serialize the following class**, either by modifying it or by forking Shapeless and modify the source of i.e. MkFieldLens?

```
  case class IdHolder[T](t: T)(implicit
                           l: MkFieldLens.Aux[T, Witness.`'id`.T, Option[Long]]){
    private def idLens = lens[T] >> 'id
  }
```

Running this test code:

```
case class Cow(sound: String, id: Option[Long])

object Testy extends App {
  val s = IdHolder(Cow("moo", Some(123L)))
  val tmp = File.createTempFile("save_test", "bin")
  val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tmp))
  oos.writeObject(s)
}
```

Produces this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: shapeless.MkFieldLens$$anon$33
```

Comment: That's a bug ... please report it.

Comment: Reported: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/issues/618